# Having an Issue when I use the function for a second time with Blazor Server side and Twilio

Tags: c#, asp.net, twilio, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have made a website with Blazor Server side. I am using Twilio Voice Api to enable the user to make an emergency call. I have been able to make the call successfully. When I leave the page and then go back to the page to make the call again I am receiving this error:

```
Error: Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Cannot read property 'setToken' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setToken' of undefined
    at a.register (https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/client/v1.3/twilio.min.js:39:420)
    at Function.setup (https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/client/v1.3/twilio.min.js:47:126)
    at Object.setup (https://localhost:44320/js/tw.js:6:23)
    at https://localhost:44320/_framework/blazor.server.js:8:31619
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at e.beginInvokeJSFromDotNet (https://localhost:44320/_framework/blazor.server.js:8:31587)
    at https://localhost:44320/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:20052
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at e.invokeClientMethod (https://localhost:44320/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:20022)
    at e.processIncomingData (https://localhost:44320/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:18006)
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeWithDefaultCancellation[T](String identifier, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeVoidAsync(IJSRuntime jsRuntime, String identifier, Object[] args)
   at QUBeMyGuest.Pages.GuestArrivals.EmergencyContact.OnAfterRenderAsync(Boolean firstRender) in C:Pages\GuestArrivals\EmergencyContact.razor:line 75
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle)
```

My api is

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Twilio.Jwt;
using Twilio.Jwt.AccessToken;
using Twilio.Jwt.Client;
using Twilio.TwiML;
using Twilio.Types;
using System.Net.Http;


namespace api.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TwilioBackEndController : ControllerBase
    {
        public readonly string AccountSid = "xxxxxx";
        public readonly string AuthToken = "xxxx";
        public readonly string AppSid = "xxxxx";
        public readonly string PhoneNumber = "xxxxx";


        [HttpGet("token")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetToken()
        {
            var scopes = new HashSet<IScope>
            {
                new OutgoingClientScope(AppSid),
                new IncomingClientScope("tester")
            };

            var capability = new ClientCapability(AccountSid, AuthToken, scopes: scopes);
            return await Task.FromResult(Content(capability.ToJwt(), "application/jwt"));
        }

        [HttpPost("voice")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostVoiceRequest([FromForm] string phone)
        {
            var destination = !phone.StartsWith('+') ? $"+{phone}" : phone;

            var response = new VoiceResponse();
            var dial = new Twilio.TwiML.Voice.Dial
            {
                CallerId = PhoneNumber
            };
            dial.Number(new PhoneNumber(destination));

            response.Append(dial);

            return await Task.FromResult(Content(response.ToString(), "application/xml"));
        }

        
    }
}
```

My emergency contact page is:

```
@page "/guest/emergencycall"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@inject HttpClient httpClient
@using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
@using System.Net.Http


<EditForm Model="Input" OnValidSubmit="InitiatePhoneCall">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <p>
        <label for="phoneNumber">Enter Phone Number:</label>
        <InputText id="phoneNumber" @bind-Value="Input.PhoneNumber"></InputText>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="@IsDialDisabled">DIAL</button>
        <button type="button" id="endBtn" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="@IsEndDisabled" @onclick="EndPhoneCall">END</button>
        <button type="button" id="clearBtn" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="@IsClearDisabled" @onclick="ClearPhoneNumber">CLEAR</button>
    </p>
</EditForm>

<hr />

@if (Logs.Count == 0)
{
    <p>No Logs available yet</p>
}
else
{
    <ul>
        @foreach (var log in Logs)
        {

            <li>@log</li>
        }
    </ul>
}

@code {
    private string _tokenUrl = "https://4b4cd1derdsb.ngrok.io/api/twiliobackend";
    private bool appSetupRun = false;

    protected bool IsDialDisabled { get; set; } = false;
    protected bool IsEndDisabled { get { return !IsDialDisabled; } }

    protected bool IsClearDisabled { get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(Input.PhoneNumber); } }
    protected List<string> Logs { get; set; } = new List<string>();

    protected InputModel Input { get; set; } = new InputModel();
    [Inject]
    protected IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }
    [Inject]
    protected IHttpClientFactory HttpClientFactory { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender && !appSetupRun)
        {
            var token = await GetClientToken();
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("appFunctions.setup", token);
            appSetupRun = true;
        }
    }

    protected async Task InitiatePhoneCall()
    {
        IsDialDisabled = true;
        await LogMessage($"Calling the number {Input.PhoneNumber}");
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("appFunctions.placeCall", Input.PhoneNumber);
        await LogMessage($"Called the number {Input.PhoneNumber}");
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    protected async Task EndPhoneCall()
    {
        IsDialDisabled = false;
        await LogMessage($"Ending the call to {Input.PhoneNumber}");
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("appFunctions.endCall");
        await LogMessage($"Ended the call to {Input.PhoneNumber}");
        StateHasChanged();

    }

    protected async Task ClearPhoneNumber()
    {
        await LogMessage("Clearing the phone number entry");
        Input.PhoneNumber = string.Empty;
        await LogMessage("Cleared the phone number entry");
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    private async Task<string> GetClientToken()
    {
        var uri = new Uri(_tokenUrl);

        using var client = HttpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    [JSInvokable]
    public async Task LogMessage(string message)
    {
        Logs.Add($"{DateTimeOffset.Now} - {message}");
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Phone(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your phone number in a proper format")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and my javascript:

```
window.appFunctions = {
    setup: function (token) {
        console.log('Getting connected');

        // Setup Twilio Device
        Twilio.Device.setup(token);

        Twilio.Device.ready(() => {
            console.log('We are connected and ready to do the thing');
        });

        Twilio.Device.error((err) => {
            console.error('This should not have been reached. We need to do something here');
            console.error(err);
        });
    },
    placeCall: function (destination) {
        console.log(`Calling ${destination}`);
        Twilio.Device.connect({ phone: destination });
        console.log(`Successfully called ${destination}`);
    },
    endCall: function () {
        console.log('Ending the call');
        Twilio.Device.disconnectAll();
        console.log('Successfully ended the call');
    }
};
```

Any suggestions would be great

Answer (score 1):

From my little experience
when Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException occur , it's often from when you call javascript
In your code please validate javascript functions which called from JSRuntime

```
   [Inject]
   protected IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }
   ...
   await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("appFunctions.setup", token);
   await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("appFunctions.placeCall", Input.PhoneNumber);
   await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("appFunctions.endCall");
```

and becuase **setToken** keyword is always used for communication setup 's function name between web and api. I guess in javascript function **appFunctions.setup** , some object became null after you go back to the page so It can't initialize.
as you can see in

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setToken' of undefined
    at a.register (https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/client/v1.3/twilio.min.js:39:420)
    at Function.setup (https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/client/v1.3/twilio.min.js:47:126)
    at Object.setup (https://localhost:44320/js/tw.js:6:23)
```

your javascript function in file **tw.js**(may be line 23?) is going to use some null object for set up communicate?